# VS Code. Disable showing errors while typing

Tags: visual-studio-code, tsconfig

I would like to not get errors until I finish typing and hit Save.
Is it possible in VS Code? Thanks

[image]

Comment: Somewhat related: [How can I easily toggle display of problem underlining in VS Code editor panels?](/q/74753185/11107541). Analogous question about jshint: [VSCode: Disable linting while typing](/q/54423732/11107541)